# Which CMS/WebApp should I choose for Staff-Works management?

Tags: web-apps, cms, wordpress

I am a member in a non-profit organization having more than 100 members. I am in the division of allocating works & getting feedback/status of works from all members. My requirement is:

I will allocate works for my members. For example I will allocate a work "Buy 25 plants" to Member-A. and another similar work to Member-B. I will get feedback/status of works allocated to my members. Emailing, Scheduling the works, too. Which CMS/WebApp should I choose for my work?

I know, Choices/Preferences depend & differ on every person's need. I am not asking a choice. I have googled as much as I could. Couldn't find any such software. So asking here a way to start my search!

Comment: Are you already using Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

You could look for a ticket system like [SpiceWorks](https://www.spiceworks.com/), where for each job you will allocate a ticket, set everybody to register or connect Spiceworks to LDAP and then you can manage the jobs effectively.

I don't know about scheduling but emailing works for sure.